# Add a directory to a Target Platform dynamically on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, pde, target-platform

I was using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and had a plugin which was adding a defined directory to the active Target Platform.

```
ITargetPlatformService service = (ITargetPlatformService) PDECore.getDefault().acquireService(ITargetPlatformService.class.getName());
ITargetDefinition target = service.getWorkspaceTargetHandle().getTargetDefinition();
IBundleContainer[] bundles = target.getBundleContainers();
String myDirectory = "C:\\directory";
boolean containsMyDirectory = false;

for (IBundleContainer bundle : bundles) {
    if (bundle.toString().contains(myDirectory.toString())) {
        containsMyDirectory = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!containsMyDirectory) {
    bundles = Arrays.copyOf(bundles, bundles.length + 1);
    bundles[bundles.length - 1] = service.newDirectoryContainer(myDirectory.toString());
    target.setBundleContainers(bundles);
    service.saveTargetDefinition(target);
    LoadTargetDefinitionJob.load(target);
}
```

But now, we're migrating to Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) and the code doesn't compile anymore, showing the following message:
The import org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional cannot be resolved

The imports that couldn't be resolved were:

```
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional.IBundleContainer;
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional.ITargetDefinition;
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional.ITargetPlatformService;
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional.LoadTargetDefinitionJob;
```

The jar used in Eclipse 3.7 is org.eclipse.pde.core_3.7.1.v20120103_r372.jar and in Eclipse 4.4 is org.eclipse.pde.core_3.10.0.v20140519-1409.jar

I couldn't find the classes that replace the old ones.

Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These classes were **internal** so you should not have been using them.

They have now all been moved to the `org.eclipse.pde.target` package in the `org.eclipse.pde.core` plugin so they are now part of the official API.

However `PDECore` is still internal so should not be used. Since `ITargetPlatformService` is an OSGi service you should be able to get it in your plugin using a `ServiceReference`.

Comment: And what about the methods ITargetDefinition.getBundleContainers() and ITargetPlatformService.newDirectoryContainer(String) that don't exist anymore?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, you are probably going to have to look at the old source and the new source to see how they changed the provisional API to the final API.